# Add single quotes to a string in terraform

Tags: string, jenkins, terraform, concatenation, single-quotes

I need to add a single quote in front of a string in terraform code that gets executed via Jenkins. The output string does not have the single quote concatenated.

Below is my code

```
{ for m in v1 : "${m.type1}:${m.type2},${m.type3}" => format("%s,name=='%s'",m.type1,m.type3) }
```

The output that I get is

```
    data1,name==John
```

I need the below output

```
    data1,name=='John'
```

When modifying the code as below

```
    { for m in v1 : "${m.type1}:${m.type2},${m.type3}" => format("%s,name=='\''%s'\''",m.type1,m.type3) }
```

I get the error Invalid escape sequence in Jenkins console ouput

```
**Error: Invalid escape sequence
The symbol "'" is not a valid escape sequence selector.**
```

Comment: What exactly is `v1`? This `for m in v1` does not seem even to be a valid TF syntax? Is it your real code?

Comment: Additionally, if you can use Jenkins Pipeline then you can easily manipulate the TF output into the format you need.

Comment: I will not be able to put the exact code here. What is the syntax for concatenating a string with single quotes in terraform

Comment: @matt Schuchard how can it be achieved?

Comment: Need to concat single quotes ' along with a string. Like John is going to be dynamic value but name==' should be added to the dynamic value and result shud be name=='John'